# BEFORE INSERT trigger, ignore certain rows at multiple insertion

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-5.7

Given table

```
CREATE TABLE testtab(
col  int
)
```

I need check inserted values and if value meets condition, then ignore these rows. So, trigger looks  something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_rows BEFORE INSERT ON testtab
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF new.col > 7 THEN
            -- here need ignore that row and do not insert
        END IF;
    END; $$
```

I can use `signal sqlstate '45000'` but problem is that when I use multiple insert syntax:

```
insert into testtab
values
(55),
(4)
```

trigger ignores all rows, but I need ignore just "55", and insert "4".

So, how to ignore certain rows and not all, when use multiple/bulk insert ?

Comment: 1. [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178129.aspx)
2. [see this also](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179250.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is really possible with the triggers i.e. ignore one item and insert another unless you raise errors with signal. This could be much easier if you perform the operation on the application level coding by checking the input values and then generate the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP then do the clean up of data in there before inserting the bulk to MySQL. Otherwise, using trigger will only allow you to insert all or nothing.